# Nginx won't to start after "$ service nginx stop"?

Tags: linux, nginx, fedora

I have this message:

```
    nginx: [emerg] location "/" is outside location "/nginx_status"...f:67
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
    nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
    Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty straight forward to me - just fix the location in the mentioned line.

Just a piece of advice would be to test your configuration each time you edit it, before stopping nginx. The command line would be something similar and simple as:

```
nginx -t -c /PATH/TO/CONF.conf
```

Comment: `service nginx configtest` could work too